# CKEDITOR 4 while using wordcount after pasting if we press any key total text is reverting back to old text

Tags: angular

in Angular im implementing ckeditor 4
while implementing wordcount maxchar was provided at that time when we paste any text and press any key then total pasted content is revering and giving undefined or removing total text

after copy paste and press any key it should keep that letter along with pasted content and if we press backspace it should not remove entire pasted content